# SQL server job / SSIS package - There was an error generating the XML document

Tags: sql-server, web-services, ssis

I currently have a problem with my SQL Server Agent Job. It used to work fine but it has stopped working all of a sudden on one of the tasks that is executed in the SSIS package.

The SSIS package consists 6 EXACTLY THE SAME web services task with a httpconnection to a webservice.

The data is pulled from the webservice and it is being written into an xml file which then is loaded into a SQL server database.

Everything is configured for the job to use it properly aswell (note: it used to work without errors).

Also when I run the package manually from data tools it doesnt give me any errors and the data is loaded perfectly fine..

The exact error I get for one of the six tasks is:

> An error occurred with the following error message:
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.Webservi
>   ceTaskException: Could not execute the Web method. The error is: There
>   was an error generating the XML document..   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebMetho
>   dInvokerProxy.InvokeMethod(DTSWebMethodInfo methodInfo, String
>   serviceName, Object connection)   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServic
>   eTaskUtil.Invoke(DTSWebMethodInfo methodInfo, String serviceName,
>   Object connection, VariableDispenser taskVariableDispenser)   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServic
>   eTask.executeThread()".

I have been looking into this error but I cannot find what is causing it.

The only thing I can think of is the filesize of the XML. Five of the six XML files are no bigger than 10MB. The one that is causing the error is more than 800MB (this used to be like 1/4 of this size when it did work).

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Go to integration services catalog -> ssisdb -> project ->right click -> reports -> standard reports. Those should tell you exact error if there's some error in ssis

Comment: Yes I know Prabhat, that is where I got the error message I posted from, but I do not understand what this error means, neither does Google. The package runs fine without errors when I run it in visual studio/data tools.

Comment: As a wild guess (not much experience with SSIS) check permissions and accounts under which the job is run. Large XML file could be a problem worth investigating as well. Can you reduce the size of the file produced by the Web Service to test this idea?

Comment: Sounds like a permission issue if you can run it from Visual Studio, but whatever account runs it somewhere else doesn't work. If using agent, the default is using an Agent Account.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, yes I can reduce the size, will give it a shot.

Comment: @KeithL Will check it, the other fives tasks seem to run fine from the job tho.

Comment: For some reason it works again after redeploying and reconfiguring the environment, I had tried this before. Oh well. Solved. :D